# TRPC, Typescript Prisma type safety with nested relations

Tags: typescript, prisma, trpc

Prisma and TS.

```
model Product {
id                String          @id @unique
name              String
description       String          @db.LongText
isSet             Boolean         @default(false)
isAvailable       Boolean         @default(false)
productLine       ProductLine     @default(NONE)
shopName          ShopName        @default(MARTIALARTS)
createdAt         DateTime        @default(now())
updatedAt         DateTime        @updatedAt
prices            Price[]
}

model Price {
productId   String
countryCode String
price       Decimal  @db.Decimal(10, 2)
discount    Decimal? @db.Decimal(10, 2)
product     Product  @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
currency    Currency @relation(fields: [countryCode], references: [countryCode])

createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
updatedAt DateTime? @updatedAt

@@id([productId, countryCode])
@@index([productId])
@@index([countryCode])
} 

model Currency {
countryCode            String  @id @unique
currencyName           String
taxRate                Decimal @db.Decimal(10, 2)
countryName            String
shippingPrice          Decimal @default(6) @db.Decimal(10, 2)
Price                  Price[]

createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
updatedAt DateTime? @updatedAt
}
```

Now When I am using my Query I am using all includes these are generated correctly with all data. Now I map over a list of products. But I cant asign the value Product as Type to the given element.
My next problem is, how can I pass this value to another component which type should I use ? None is working. I just want full typesafety with TS but I am not able to pass a simple query with 2 nested relations to it